# Improving the performance of Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication, c99

This is my code for speeding up matrix multiplication, but it is only 5% faster than the simple one.
What can i do to boost it as much as possible?

*The tables are being accessed for example as: **C[sub2ind(i,j,n)]** for the **C[i, j]** position.

```
void matrixMultFast(float * const C,            /* output matrix */
                float const * const A,      /* first matrix */
                float const * const B,      /* second matrix */
                int const n,                /* number of rows/cols */
                int const ib,               /* size of i block */
                int const jb,               /* size of j block */
                int const kb)               /* size of k block */
{

int i=0, j=0, jj=0, k=0, kk=0;
float sum;

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        C[sub2ind(i,j,n)]=0;

for(kk=0;kk<n;kk+=kb)
{
    for(jj=0;jj<n;jj+=jb)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(j=jj;j<jj+jb;j++)
            {
                sum=C[sub2ind(i,j,n)];
                for(k=kk;k<kk+kb;k++)
                    sum += A[sub2ind(i,k,n)]*B[sub2ind(k,j,n)];
                C[sub2ind(i,j,n)]=sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
} // end function 'matrixMultFast4'
```

*It is written in C and it needs to support C99

Comment: You could use SIMD extensions to speed it way up.

Comment: There are good softwares out there that do this for you called BLAS (basic linear algebra subprograms), and the routine you're looking for is called DGEMM (but there are plenty of others that optimize for specific types of matrix multiplication). GotoBLAS, OpenBLAS, Intel's MKL, AMD's ACML to name a few. If you really want to speed up your own version you need to use vectorization and parallelization.

Comment: Transpose one of your inputs so you can access rows of one matrix and columns of the other both as contiguous memory.  Your `B[sub2ind(k,j,n)]` is the problem, because it's striding by `n` every iteration of the inner loop, giving you terrible cache access locality.  If you fix that, then your attempt at cache-blocking could help a lot. 
 Also, just use `memset` to zero `C[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many, many things you can do to improve the efficiency of matrix multiplication.

To examine how to improve the basic algorithm, let's first take a look at our current options. The naive implementation, of course, has 3 loops with a time complexity of the order of `O(n^3)`. There is another method called Strassen's Method which achieves a appreciable speedup and has the order of `O(n^2.73)` (but in practice is useless since it offers no appreciable means of optimization).

This is in theory. Now consider how matrices are stored in memory. Row major is the standard, but you find column major too. Depending on the scheme, transposing your matrix might improve speed due to fewer cache misses. Matrix multiplication in theory is just a bunch of vector dot products and addition. The same vector is to be operated upon by multiple vectors, thus it makes sense to keep that vector in cache for faster access.

Now, with the introduction of multiple cores, parallelism and the cache concept, the game changes. If we look a little closely, we see that a dot product is nothing but a bunch of multiplications followed by summations. These multiplications can be done in parallel. Hence, we can now look at parallel loading of numbers.

Now let's make things a little more complicated. When talking about matrix multiplication, there is a distinction between single floating point and double floating point in their size. Often the former is 32 bits while the latter, 64 (of course, this depends on the CPU). Each CPU only has a fixed number of registers, meaning the bigger your numbers, the lesser you can fit in the CPU. Moral of the story is, stick to single floating point unless you really need double.

Now that we've gone through the basics of how we can tune matrix multiplication, worry not. You need do nothing of what has been discussed above since there are already subroutines to do it. As mentioned in the comments, there's GotoBLAS, OpenBLAS, Intel's MKL, and Apple's Accelerate framework. MKL/Accelerate are proprietary, but OpenBLAS is a very competitive alternative.

Here's a nice little example that multiplies 2 8k x 8k matrices in a few milliseconds on my Macintosh:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

int SIZE = 8192;

typedef float point_t;

point_t* transpose(point_t* A) {    
    point_t* At = (point_t*) calloc(SIZE * SIZE, sizeof(point_t));    
    vDSP_mtrans(A, 1, At, 1, SIZE, SIZE);

    return At;
}

point_t* dot(point_t* A, point_t* B) {
    point_t* C = (point_t*) calloc(SIZE * SIZE, sizeof(point_t));       
    int i;    
    int step = (SIZE * SIZE / 4);

    cblas_sgemm (CblasRowMajor, 
       CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, SIZE/4, SIZE, SIZE,
       1.0, &A[0], SIZE, B, SIZE, 0.0, &C[0], SIZE);

    cblas_sgemm (CblasRowMajor, 
       CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, SIZE/4, SIZE, SIZE,
       1.0, &A[step], SIZE, B, SIZE, 0.0, &C[step], SIZE);

    cblas_sgemm (CblasRowMajor, 
       CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, SIZE/4, SIZE, SIZE,
       1.0, &A[step * 2], SIZE, B, SIZE, 0.0, &C[step * 2], SIZE);

    cblas_sgemm (CblasRowMajor, 
       CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, SIZE/4, SIZE, SIZE,
       1.0, &A[step * 3], SIZE, B, SIZE, 0.0, &C[step * 3], SIZE);      

    return C;
}

void print(point_t* A) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%f  ", A[i * SIZE + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    for(; SIZE <= 8192; SIZE *= 2) {
        point_t* A = (point_t*) calloc(SIZE * SIZE, sizeof(point_t));
        point_t* B = (point_t*) calloc(SIZE * SIZE, sizeof(point_t));

        srand(getpid());

        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i < SIZE * SIZE; i++) {
            A[i] = ((point_t)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
            B[i] = ((point_t)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
        }

        struct timeval t1, t2;
        double elapsed_time;

        gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
        point_t* C = dot(A, B);
        gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);

        elapsed_time = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
        elapsed_time += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms

        printf("Time taken for %d size matrix multiplication: %lf\n", SIZE, elapsed_time/1000.0);

        free(A);
        free(B);
        free(C);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

At this point I should also mention SSE (Streaming SIMD Extension), which is basically something you shouldn't do unless you've worked with assembly. Basically, you're *vectorising* your C code, to work with vectors instead of integers. This means you can operate on blocks of data instead of single values. The compiler gives up and just translates your code as is without doing its own optimizations. If done right, it can speed up your code like nothing before - you can touch the theoretical floor of `O(n^2)` even! But it is easy to abuse SSE, and most people unfortunately do, making the end result worse than before.

I hope this motivates you to dig deeper. The world of matrix multiplication is a large and fascinating one. Below, I attach links for further reading.

1. [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net)
2. [More about SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)
3. [Intel Intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)

Comment: Thanks! My problem is that i can't use other libraries, it is an exercise that will be compiled on another computer. I can use SIMD (and i have worked with assembly), but i don't know how to use it.

Comment: If you're working with large matrices the option is always there to transpose and/or decompose your matrices. And yes, SIMD is not for the faint hearted.