# Matrix Multiplication of size 100*100 using SSE Intrinsics

Tags: c, sse, matrix-multiplication, intrinsics

```
    int MAX_DIM = 100;
    float a[MAX_DIM][MAX_DIM]__attribute__   ((aligned(16)));
    float b[MAX_DIM][MAX_DIM]__attribute__   ((aligned(16)));
    float d[MAX_DIM][MAX_DIM]__attribute__   ((aligned(16)));
    /*
     * I fill these arrays with some values
     */

for(int i=0;i<MAX_DIM;i+=1){

      for(int j=0;j<MAX_DIM;j+=4){

        for(int k=0;k<MAX_DIM;k+=4){

          __m128 result = _mm_load_ps(&d[i][j]);

          __m128 a_line  = _mm_load_ps(&a[i][k]);

          __m128 b_line0 = _mm_load_ps(&b[k][j+0]);

          __m128 b_line1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&b[k][j+1]);

          __m128 b_line2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&b[k][j+2]);

          __m128 b_line3 = _mm_loadu_ps(&b[k][j+3]);

         result = _mm_add_ps(result, _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(a_line, a_line, 0x00), b_line0));
         result = _mm_add_ps(result, _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(a_line, a_line, 0x55), b_line1));
         result = _mm_add_ps(result, _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(a_line, a_line, 0xaa), b_line2));
         result = _mm_add_ps(result, _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(a_line, a_line, 0xff), b_line3));
         _mm_store_ps(&d[i][j],result);
        }
      }
    }
```

the above code I made to make matrix multiplication using SSE. the code runs as flows I take  4 elements from row from a multiply it by 4 elements from a column from b and move to the next 4 elements in the row of a and next 4 elements in column b

I get an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` I don't really know why

I use gcc  5.4.0 on ubuntu 16.04.5

Edit : 
The segmentation fault was solved by _mm_loadu_ps
Also there is something wrong with logic i will be greatfull if someone helps me to  find it

Comment: It looks like you might be using GCC under Linux.  Please update your post with the following info: a) OS, b) Compiler and version, c) Run in gdb (if applicable) and copy/paste your stack trace.

Comment: Some of your loads (the last 3) are misaligned - use `_mm_loadu_ps` for these (or for all of them).

Answer (score 3):

> The segmentation fault was solved by `_mm_loadu_ps` Also there is something wrong with logic...

You're loading 4 overlapping windows on `b[k][j+0..7]`.  (This is why you needed `loadu`).

Perhaps you meant to load `b[k][j+0]`, `+4`, `+8`, `+12`?  If so, you should align `b` by 64, so all four loads come from the same cache line (for performance).  Strided access is not great, but using all 64 bytes of every cache line you touch is a lot better than getting row-major vs. column-major totally wrong in scalar code with no blocking.

> I take 4 elements from row from `a` multiply it by 4 elements from a column from `b`

I'm not sure your text description describes your code.

Unless you've already transposed `b`, you can't load multiple values from the same column with a SIMD load, because they aren't contiguous in memory.

C multidimensional arrays are "row major": the last index is the one that varies most quickly when moving to the next higher memory address.  Did you think that `_mm_loadu_ps(&b[k][j+1])` was going to give you `b[k+0..3][j+1]`?  If so, this is a duplicate of [SSE matrix-matrix multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313434/sse-matrix-matrix-multiplication) (That question is using 32-bit integer, not 32-bit float, but same layout problem.  See that for a working loop structure.)

---

To debug this, put a simple pattern of values into `b[]`.  Like

```
#include <stdalign.>

alignas(64) float b[MAX_DIM][MAX_DIM] = {
    0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, ...,
    0100, 0101, 0102, ...,
    0200, 0201, 0202, ...,
 };

 // i.e. for (...) b[i][j] = 100 * i + j;
```

Then when you step through your code in the debugger, you can see what values end up in your vectors.

For your `a[][]` values, maybe use `90000.0 + 100 * i + j` so if you're looking at registers (instead of C variables) you can still tell which values are `a` and which are `b`.

---

Related:

- [Ulrich Drepper's **What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory**](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) shows an optimized matmul with cache-blocking with SSE instrinsics for double-precision.  Should be straightforward to adapt for `float`.
- [How does BLAS get such extreme performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303182/how-does-blas-get-such-extreme-performance)  (You might want to just use an optimized matmul library; tuning matmul for optimal cache-blocking is non-trivial but important)
- [Matrix Multiplication with blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375076/matrix-multiplication-with-blocks)
- [Poor maths performance in C vs Python/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552143/poor-maths-performance-in-c-vs-python-numpy) has some links to other questions
- [how to optimize matrix multiplication (matmul) code to run fast on a single processor core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401524/how-to-optimize-matrix-multiplication-matmul-code-to-run-fast-on-a-single-proc)